# gadicohen:sitemaps meteor package : I'd like to add a page without erasing the others

Tags: javascript, meteor, sitemap

Like said in the title, I'm using gadicohen:sitemaps meteor package to handle the sitemap.xml file for my website.

There's a big problem : on each call of sitemaps.add('/sitemap.xml', []), the function erases the entire sitemap.xml file to put the brackets's content instead; but when I call this function, I'd like to add the brackets's content to the tail on the file without erasing it.

There's another way to use the function :

```js
sitemaps.add('/sitemap.xml', function() {
  return [];
});
```

I'm using this one because it enables me to create an array, to fill it with the pages I need, then to return it.
But I'd like to update dynamically the file (each time a thread is created), that's why I need to add pages to the tail instead of erasing the entire file each time I call the function.

Thank you for the attention you give to help me =)